# onblur vs onclick timing

Tags: javascript, event-handling

There is a `textarea` element which converts itself into a `div` when `onblur` event happens on that same `textarea`. There is also a `button` which has its `onclick` property set to `function f`.

If one is writing in the `textarea` and then clicks on a `button`, `f` is fired, but also `onblur` event handler is triggered. Is there some order rules in this case, or the two handler functions may fire in random order?

Comment: I don't get the reason for the onblur event?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z5SEp/

The events for latest Chrome seem to be:

```
mousedown
blur
mouseup
click
```

Although I could not find any documentation to rely on, it would make sense to me that blur is fired after mousedown, but before mouseup. Mousedown causes blur, but you could leave your mouse button down for an extended period of time and still cause a blur.

The order of click events will always be 1. mousedown 2. mouseup 3. click. The blur makes sense to be after mousedown but before mouseup.

---

*More things to keep in mind*

If you trigger the button click like this: `$('button').trigger('click');`, then the blur event will *not* fire, and focus will remain on the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, the blur will always fire first because blur is triggered as soon as the mouse button goes down elsewhere on the page. So when the mouse goes down on your button, the textarea's blur event is fired first. As the mouse comes up, the button's click event is fired.

Comment: no, onblur is fired when the textarea looses the focus, not when the mouse goes away