# "blur" event being triggered for no reason?

Tags: javascript, events, blur

I have 2 elements. The first element has a `blur` event, and the second element has a `mousedown` event. The `mousedown` event on the second element returns the focus to the first element, but `blur` on the first element is triggered for some reason, even if the first element wasn't focused before `mousedown`ing the second element.

Why does this happen? Is this (somehow) desired behaviour, or is this some kind of bug?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bug?</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" />
<br /><br />
<button>Click me to focus on the input</button>
<br /><br />
<input type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('blur', function(e){
        console.log('blur', e);
    });

    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
        console.log('mousedown', e);

        document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rsh5aopg/

Comment: I expect the following behaviour: mousedown ( focus on the button ) -> function changes focus (focus on the input) -> mouseup (focus on the button => blur of the input).

Comment: @Edwin is correct, or so it seems. Out of interest, why are you using `mousedown` and not `click`?

Comment: I don't think so... mouseup fires /after/ blur. The events fire in order mousedown, blur, mouseup, click. I need to do some stuff before blur is run, which is why I'm using mousedown instead of click. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867022/onblur-vs-onclick-timing

Comment: I just added a mouseup event to the second element... it triggers after the blur. The blur is not being caused by mouseup.

Comment: you have two blurs, one for the input and one for the button

Comment: The event listener is only supposed to trigger when the first input blurs... The first input doesn't blur if you just click the button or if you make sure the second input is in focus when you click the button. The first input should not cause blur to trigger if it is not focused before clicking the button

Comment: add a `focus` event listener to your button and you will understand. Btw all this events are default events and they exists already on components.

Comment: I see... So the button is focused by the browser after mousedown triggers... Why is it not focused before mousedown triggers?

Comment: it is before the mousedown. If you add an focus event to the button you will get the following: `focus->mousedown->blur(input)->focus->mouseup` (*this only you don't have already the focus on mousedown - if you have the focus then the first focus is out)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147935/discussion-between-chat-tor-and-edwin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, the event sequence is:

```
mousedown
blur
mouseup
click
```

When you press the button, the `mousedown` event is triggered.  Within that listener, you focus the first input.  Naturally, after the mousedown event, the blur event happens.  This takes away focus from first input and you see the blur listener code execute.

You can either add `e.preventDefault()` to the mousedown event, or use either `mouseup` or `click` as those both happen after the blur.  Either way, the first input will still have focus as you desire.

Comment: Regardless of exact implementation, the thing that I didn't understand was that the browser changes focus to the clicked element after mousedown but before mouseup. This isn't obvious, but, after thinking about it for a while, it makes sense that focus/blur should happen together. Also, your answer solves this problem by not making the browser focus on the button. Thank you

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` works if you want the current event to function normally otherwise (put cursor in text bot, toggle a checkbox, etc) and only want to stop other events from firing.